# Making a table in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, datatable

I am trying to with a set of data make a table with just two columns.  Below is the following data:

```
data = [[ 66386, 174296,  75131, 577908,  32015],
    [ 58230, 381139,  78045,  99308, 160454],
    [ 89135,  80552, 152558, 497981, 603535],
    [ 78415,  81858, 150656, 193263,  69638],
    [139361, 331509, 343164, 781380,  52269]]
```

I just want to display the first column of the data so that I can table that looks like this below:

[image: at]

Below is a snippet of code that I am trying to use:

```
columns = ('Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail')
rows = ['%d year' % x for x in (100, 50, 20, 10, 5)]


# Get some pastel shades for the colors
colors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(rows)))
n_rows = len(data)


# Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
y_offset = np.zeros(len(columns))

# Plot bars and create text labels for the table
cell_text = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    y_offset = data[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % (x / 1000.0) for x in y_offset])
# Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
colors = colors[::-1]


 the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='center')
```

How do I tweak this code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

add an attribute 'year' for example in columns

```
columns = ('year','Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail')
rows = ['%d year' % x for x in (100, 50, 20, 10, 5)]


# Get some pastel shades for the colors
colors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(rows)))
n_rows = len(data)


# Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
y_offset = np.zeros(len(columns))

# Plot bars and create text labels for the table
cell_text = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    y_offset = data[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % (x / 1000.0) for x in y_offset])
# Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
colors = colors[::-1]


 the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='center')
```